# Undo , Redo in Javascript With Local Storage

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

Undo and Redo in Javascript and every event i want to store in local storage as a object

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/fdq68tbc/)

```
[http://jsfiddle.net/fdq68tbc/][1]
```

Comment: Your fidddle says : `selectedPath.css is not a function`

Comment: and i dont see any code for  Local Storage , so post relevant code

Comment: Update your question by adding more details on what you're actually trying to achieve.

Comment: @MokshShah Check Now Updated One http://jsfiddle.net/fdq68tbc/1/

Comment: It has a same error.

Comment: @MokshShah Updated link is http://jsfiddle.net/fdq68tbc/2/

Comment: @tripx Have added an answer, have look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

**Markup**

```
<svg width="300" height="100">
    <rect width="300" height="100" id="select1" />
</svg>
<br/>
<br/>
<button class="btn" id="btn-test1" data-color="#ff0000">Red</button>
<button class="btn" id="btn-test2" data-color="#00ff00">Green</button>
<button class="btn" id="btn-test3" data-color="#0000ff">Blue</button>
<hr/>
<input type="button" value="Undo" id="btnUndo">
<input type="button" value="Redo" id="btnRedo">
```

**Script**

```
$('.btn').on('click', function () {
    var pathToSet = localStorage.getItem('lastColor');
    localStorage.setItem('UndoColor', $("#select1").css("fill"));
    selectedPath.css({
        fill: $(this).attr('data-color')
    });
    localStorage.setItem('RedoColor', $("#select1").css("fill"));
});

$("#btnUndo").click(function () {
    var pathToSet = localStorage.getItem('UndoColor');


    selectedPath.css({
        fill: pathToSet
    });

});
$("#btnRedo").click(function () {
    var pathToSet = localStorage.getItem('RedoColor');


    selectedPath.css({
        fill: pathToSet
    });

});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/mokshshah/fdq68tbc/4/)

Comment: i want undo steps and redo steps not only 1 step , can you help me, i want multiple undo steps and redo steps

Comment: @tripx, I've updated my answer for multiple undo steps, same thing you need to do for Redo.

Comment: Thanks Man, i got it, this is the link right? http://jsfiddle.net/mokshshah/fdq68tbc/4/

and can i store images instead of color ?

Comment: Yes definitely you can, you may store image path in `LocalStorage`.

Comment: am not able get redo functionality can you help me

Comment: Its supposed to be same as undo, if you're facing any other issue then you may raise a new question for that.

Comment: if i have multiple svg path's ?

Comment: store them in an array object

Comment: Please check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/mpqbs7zc/ redo and array not working